MFA設定必須のCognitoのクロスアカウントマイグレーション　移行先Cognitoにユーザープロファイルが作成されない
現在、AWSテナント移行を行っておりCognitoのデータ移行が必要になっています。
公式から以下２つのソリューションが提供されていますが、今回パスワードリセットといったユーザーアクションを極力なくす方針から、移行用Lambdaトリガーを利用しています。
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-import-using-lambda.html
Lambdaトリガーの実行と、移行元Cognitoでの認証情報の検証は正常に通っていて、Lambdaからは公式に則り以下のレスポンスを返していますが、移行先Cognitoにユーザープロファイルが作成されていない状況です。
原因や勘所が分かる方は、コメント下さい。
{
  version: '1',
  triggerSource: 'UserMigration_Authentication',
  region: 'xxx',
  userPoolId: 'xxxx',
  userName: 'xxxx',
  callerContext: {
    awsSdkVersion: 'aws-sdk-unknown-unknown',
    clientId: 'xxxxx'
  },
  request: { password: 'XXXXX', validationData: {}, userAttributes: null },
  response: {
    userAttributes: {
      username: 'name',
      'custom:role': 'x',
      'custom:userId': 'xxxxxxxx',
      phone_number: '+99999999',
      preferred_username: 'name',
      sub: 'uuid'
    },
    forceAliasCreation: false,
    enableSMSMFA: true,
    finalUserStatus: 'CONFIRMED',
    messageAction: 'SUPPRESS',
    desiredDeliveryMediums: 'SMS'
  }
}

実装したLambdaトリガーは以下の形です。
// migration Lambda trigger code
import {
  AdminInitiateAuthCommand,
  AuthFlowType,
  CognitoIdentityProviderClient,
  AdminGetUserCommand
} from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider";
import { STSClient, AssumeRoleCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-sts"

const region = "ap-northeast-1"

const roleARN = "arn:aws:iam::XXXX:role/XXXX"
const FROM_USER_POOL_ID = "XXXX"
const FROM_CLIENT_ID = "XXXX"

// Replace this mock with a call to a real authentication service.
const authenticateUser = async (username, password) => {
  console.log(username+" + " + password)
  const stsClient = new STSClient({region:region})
  const stsCommand = new AssumeRoleCommand({
    RoleArn: roleARN,
    RoleSessionName: "sts-role-test"
  })
  console.log("assumeRole Invoke")
  const assumeRoleResponse = await stsClient.send(stsCommand)
  console.log(assumeRoleResponse)
  
  const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({
    region: region,
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: assumeRoleResponse.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: assumeRoleResponse.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: assumeRoleResponse.Credentials.SessionToken
    }
  });
  const command = new AdminInitiateAuthCommand({
    ClientId: FROM_CLIENT_ID,
    UserPoolId: FROM_USER_POOL_ID,
    AuthFlow: AuthFlowType.ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH,
    AuthParameters: { USERNAME: username, PASSWORD: password },
  });
  const result = await client.send(command);
  console.log(result)
  const getUserInputs = new AdminGetUserCommand({
    Username: username,
    UserPoolId: FROM_USER_POOL_ID,
  });
  const userInfo = await client.send(getUserInputs);
  console.log('userInfo')
  console.log(userInfo)
  return result
};

const getUserInfo = async (username) => {
  console.log('getUserInfo')
  console.log(username)
  const stsClient = new STSClient({region:region})
  const stsCommand = new AssumeRoleCommand({
    RoleArn: roleARN,
    RoleSessionName: "sts-role-test"
  })
  const assumeRoleResponse = await stsClient.send(stsCommand)
  const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({
    region: region,
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: assumeRoleResponse.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: assumeRoleResponse.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: assumeRoleResponse.Credentials.SessionToken
    }
  });
  const getUserInputs = new AdminGetUserCommand({
    Username: username,
    UserPoolId: FROM_USER_POOL_ID,
  });
  const userInfo = await client.send(getUserInputs);
  console.log('userInfo')
  console.log(userInfo)
  return userInfo
};

export const handler = async (event) => {
  if (event.triggerSource == "UserMigration_Authentication") {
    console.log("in if UserMigration_Authentication")
    // Authenticate the user with your existing user directory service
    const user = await authenticateUser(event.userName, event.request.password);
    console.log("user is ")
    console.log(user)
    const userInfo = await getUserInfo(event.userName)
    let sub;
    let adminRole;
    let userId;
    let phone_number;
    let preferred_username;
  for (const userAttribute of userInfo.UserAttributes) {
    switch (userAttribute.Name) {
      case 'sub':
        sub = userAttribute.Value;
        break;
      case 'custom:role':
        adminRole = userAttribute.Value;
        break;
      case 'custom:userId':
        userId = userAttribute.Value;
        break;
      case 'phone_number':
        phone_number = userAttribute.Value;
        break;
      case 'preferred_username':
        preferred_username = userAttribute.Value;
        break;
      default:
        break;
  }
}
    if (user) {
      event.response.userAttributes = {
        username: event.userName,
        'custom:role': role,
        'custom:userId': userId,
        phone_number: phone_number,
        preferred_username: preferred_username,
        sub: sub
      };
      event.response.finalUserStatus = "CONFIRMED";
      event.response.messageAction = "SUPPRESS";
      event.response.desiredDeliveryMediums = "SMS";
      event.response.forceAliasCreation = false;
      event.response.enableSMSMFA = true;
    }
  }
  console.log(event)
  return event;
};

移行先Cognitoからは、ユーザー名かパスワードが誤っているエラーが返却される
{
    "code": "NotAuthorizedException",
    "name": "NotAuthorizedException",
    "message": "Incorrect username or password."
}

以下のイメージ
Aテナント→移行元のCognitoが存在
Bテナント→移行先のCognitoとLambdaトリガーが存在
Lambdaトリガーには、AテナントでCognitoへアクセスするIAMロールを作成した上で設定している。（原因切り分けの為、Cogntioのパワーユーザーも付けてる。）
既存の認証フローは以下。
①ユーザーは画面（Vue3）からIDとパスワードを入力しログイン
②aws-sdk/amplifyで、Cognitoに認証をかけにいく→ここでLambdaトリガーが実行され、移行元Cognitoで認証＋認証結果の返却とユーザープロファイルを移行先Cognitoで作成される想定をしている。
③認証が成功すれば、SMSによる認証コードが送付され、Cognitoのレスポンス結果に応じてSMS認証入力画面に遷移
④SMS認証コードを入力し、再度Cognitoに認証をかける
⑤問題なければ、コンテンツにアクセスする

userAttributesにsub属性を指定することはできないようです。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62378173/migrating-users-from-one-aws-cognito-pool-to-another-keeping-the-cognitoid-sub-v

コメントありがとうございます。こちら自己解決出来ました。
↑のコメントで頂いている通り、subは指定できないのに加え、電話番号の整合性チェックや、UserAttributeの整合性もCognitoの内部で確認している模様です。
テストデータも含まれていたため、以下のようなデータの整合性が一致しておらず登録されなかった模様。
・phone_number_verifiedがTrueなのに、Phone_numberが登録されていない
・email_verifiedがTrueなので、Emailが登録されていない
・Phone_numberが明らかにおかしい値（9999999999999999999999)とか
